# ScoreNinja causes java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I'm trying to add ScoreNinja, the global high score system, to my Android game, and it works fine when I load it on my phone, but when I release it into the wild, I got crash reports saying:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Here is part of the call stack:

```
android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:99)
android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:65)
android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:61)
android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:797)
android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:812)
com.scoreninja.adapter.ScoreNinjaAdapter.show(ScoreNinjaAdapter.java:136)
com.scoreninja.adapter.ScoreNinjaAdapter.show(ScoreNinjaAdapter.java:99)
```

I thought the main thread had prepare() called automatically, and if not, why would it work fine for me but not anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what was wrong, but for anyone who has the same problem, it works fine if you break up your game into a menu Activity and a game Activity. Have the game activity return a score to the menu activity on a game over, then call all the ScoreNinja stuff from the menu activity.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're creating the handler outside of the main thread.  Create the handler in the `onCreate` of your activity or something similar, something that'll definitely be in the main thread, and then you can call `handler.post(runnable)` inside your other thread.