# Android: I am getting reports of 'Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()' after adding ScoreNinja

Tags: android, scoreninja

I am getting reports of 'Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()' once I added ScoreNinja to my Android app, and released it to the market.

It seems that it isn't happening all the time as the ScoreNinja highscore has lots of entries from users.

I have looked on the web for help but there are no clear directions on what to do.

I have used the ScoreNinja code exactly as shown on the scoreninja website.

Thanks for any help.

Dave B

BTW If anyone is having problems with ScoreNinja only displaying one score, check to see if the launchmode is not set to 'singleinstance' in your manifest. This fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize everything inside app lifecycle methods (e.g. `onCreate()`) and not as static final fields.

Answer (score 0):

See:

[ScoreNinja causes java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603846/scoreninja-causes-java-lang-runtimeexception-cant-create-handler-inside-thread)

It fixed it for me to call .show() in a normal activity after the game thread has ended.